# MS Reporting, trouble with repeating values

Tags: reporting-services, row, reporting, rows

MS Reporting provides two types of tables (sorry, I don't remember what property is responsible for this)

First one: (as is)

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ abc  ║  321 ║
║    2 ║ abc  ║  643 ║
║    3 ║ abc  ║  643 ║
║    4 ║ def  ║  643 ║
║    5 ║ def  ║  529 ║
║    6 ║ def  ║  529 ║
║    7 ║ ghi  ║  529 ║
║    8 ║ ghi  ║  529 ║
║    9 ║ ghi  ║  529 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

And the second: (doesn't repeat duplicates)

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ abc  ║  321 ║
║    2 ║      ║  643 ║
║    3 ║      ║      ║
║    4 ║ def  ║      ║
║    5 ║      ║  529 ║
║    6 ║      ║      ║
║    7 ║ ghi  ║      ║
║    8 ║      ║      ║
║    9 ║      ║      ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

If there are many rows, the second is more preferred. But for my customer it looks weird. He says:"This table consists empty values!"

My question for community: Can I use not empty string, for example, "-||-", and what should I do to this? It would look like this:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ abc  ║  321 ║
║    2 ║ -||- ║  643 ║
║    3 ║ -||- ║ -||- ║
║    4 ║ def  ║ -||- ║
║    5 ║ -||- ║  529 ║
║    6 ║ -||- ║ -||- ║
║    7 ║ ghi  ║ -||- ║
║    8 ║ -||- ║ -||- ║
║    9 ║ -||- ║ -||- ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for repeated values using the [Previous](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx) function, and apply place holder values based on this using an expression in the Textbox.

e.g. To replace repeated *Col2* values with `-||-`:

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Col2.Value) <> Fields!Col2.Value
  , Fields!Col2.Value
  , "-||-")
```

**Edit after comment**

Since the report is rendered after data is extracted/loaded, there's no way to say when a page break has occurred in code.

However, if you have fixed rows heights and can predict how many rows will appear on a page, you might be able to consider a row number to help here.

Say you know you're going to get 20 rows per page, you can use something like:

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Col2.Value) <> Fields!Col2.Value
    or RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 20 = 1
  , Fields!Col2.Value
  , "-||-")
```

So for row 1, 21, etc, it was always show the value.

Comment: It doesn't work. It works only for first duplicate, and the next ones are empty

Comment: I have set "HideDuplicates" to none, it works, but on the next page repeated value equals "-||-" too, how can it be it's real value for only first row on new page?

Comment: You can't really predict page breaks in advance, but there is a workaround to consider in some cases - please see edit.